# Can't Find Data Lake Store Gen2

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to locate Azure DataLake Store Gen2 using the Azure portal and for some reason cannot find it:

[image]

I've been searching the docs and the portal and cannot seem to find it, has anyone else run into this problem? It has been in global GA since Feb, so I don't think that's the issue. I've reviewed the [docs for how to create a Storage Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-quickstart-create-account), is that all that's needed to create the gen2 instance?

Comment: Notice under Storage Account, it lists "Data Lake Gen 2"

Comment: @HongOoi yep, missed that because I was looking for an option like ADLS Gen1, rather than thinking it was a part of Storage Account

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ADLS gen 2 is a feature of Azure Storage. When you are creating a Storage account, go to the Advanced tab:

[image: choose Advanced tab]

Then enable Hierarchical namespace (this provides you ADLS Gen 2):

[image: ADLS hierarchical namespace]

Comment: Thanks, it's just weirdly counter-intuitive that it wouldn't be a quick option like it was for gen1

Comment: @C.Nivs ADLSgen2 is still in preview, and isn't fully integrated with the other storage options yet. Presumably when everything is fixed up, there will be something more prominent in the marketplace

Comment: @HongOoi it is? Because it says that it's been [in GA since Feb 1, 2019](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-is-now-generally-available/)

Comment: not sure if this is a type or it's been renamed but "Azure Storage" is listed as "storage account" in Azure.